# how to set image src from folder on server and make slide show using javascript , c#

Tags: javascript, c#, html

I am trying to set the image src dynamically but i do not know how to set image src at the run time. I am building a traveling website and have multiple folders for accommodations images. i saved path in database and want a run time slideshow. please help me, this is my code

```
<h2 class="w3-center"> Slideshow</h2>
    <div class="w3-content" style="max-width:800px;position:relative">
        <img class="mySlides" src="Images/page.jpeg" style="width:100%">
        <img class="mySlides" src="slideshow-housing/large/kimba/2.jpg" style="width:100%">
        <img class="mySlides" src="slideshow-housing/large/kimba/1.jpg" style="width:100%">

        <!-- Controls -->
        <a class='left carousel-control' href='#carousel-custom' data-slide='prev'onclick="plusDivs(-1)">
            <span class='glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left'></span>
        </a>
        <a class='right carousel-control' href='#carousel-custom' data-slide='next'onclick="plusDivs(1)">
            <span class='glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right'></span>
        </a>
    </div> 
    <script>
         var myHidden = document.getElementById("<%:strPath.ClientID%>");

         var slideIndex = 1;
         showDivs(slideIndex);

         function plusDivs(n) {
             showDivs(slideIndex += n);
         }

         function showDivs(n) {
            var i;
            var x = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
            if (n > x.length) { slideIndex = 1 }
            if (n < 1) { slideIndex = x.length }
            for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
                x[i].style.display = "none";
            }
            x[slideIndex - 1].style.display = "block";
        }
    </script>
```

server side code

```
string path = accom.SlideShow;
string strPath = "~/" + path;
string[] filesindirectory = System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(Server.MapPath(strPath));
List<String> images = new List<string>(filesindirectory.Count());

foreach (string item in filesindirectory)
{
    images.Add(String.Format("~/Images/{0}", System.IO.Path.GetFileName(item)));
}
```

Comment: http://forums.asp.net/t/1900377.aspx?Dynamically+slide+show+images+on+jquery+slider+from+SQL+database

Answer (score 0):

you can set an elements src attribute like:

```
$("#element").attr("src", "your.url");
```

Note: if you're using [jquery](http://jquery.com)